# Access Chef node name within environment

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm setting up chef with vagrant and having trouble getting the current node name for use in configuration.

My vagrant config has:

```
  config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.node_name = 'test123'
  end
```

And my chef environment has:

```
override_attributes["app1"] = {
    "domain" => "ma-#{Chef::Config[:node_name]}.app1.local"
}
```

However I don't get the correct value for node_name as set in the VagrantFile. How can I access the chef node name within my environment file?

Or, alternatively, how can I override the "domain" attribute directly from my VagrantFile?

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
node.name
```

See also:

```
node['fqdn']
node['hostname']
```